Grafana v10 Heatmap vs v7
Grafana gurus...
We recently upgraded one of our grafana's to v10 (10.4.1), and noticed the way the heatmap vis displays data has shifted when compared to v7 (7.5.7). The heatmaps in question are being derived from influx (1.8) data.
Example/reference data is
time                      val
----                      ---
2024-05-10T12:20:00+12:00 65
2024-05-10T12:40:00+12:00 70

Query to influx has GROUP BY time(20m), and mean(val)

v7 for example puts to '65' value between 12:20 and 12:40, and v10 puts it between 12:00 and: 12:20.
The v10 panel was an inplace upgrade from v7, and the v7 was exported from v10 for comparison.
I guess this behaviour change could have been implemented much earlier (v8, v9 etc).
Has anyone else noticed this difference?
Is this just a preferential change?
Is the v10 heatmap more technically correct?
We like the v7 version, is there anyway to get v10 to behave the same way?
Thanks in advance!
